# What is the play-on-words regarding the word "табельный" in this context?

Tags: перевод, meme

I was sent this meme by a friend, and although I can read and understand it in a literal sense, I am failing to understand what about the usage of these words is comical.

I believe the text roughly translates to "Andre Ilyich is stern yet gentle to himself on the timetable- he glued a sticker of a cat"

I understand that the gun would be the timetable. What is the play on words?

[image]

Comment: The text lacks punctuation, this making it harder to understand. There should be ":" or at least "," after "нежен". And comma before "но", but this is obvious.

Comment: @AlexVB this type of text (poroshki) usually lacks punctuation, it's part of the genre.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the timetable thing. `ТТ` is `Тульский Токарев`, a handgun. `Табельное [оружие]`, or [`служебное оружие`](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ruwiki/1405020) is a service pistol, issued to,
 e.g. police officers. (By the way, `ТТ` is not used as a service pistol anymore, as far as I know.) As `Токарев` is a male surname, the adjective is used as `табельный`.

So, the guy sticked a cute cate™ pic to his service pistol, which should be a pun.

Answer (score 4):

> Andrey Ilyich is stern yet gentle
>   onto his service "TT" gun
>   he glued a sticker with a *kitty* from a gum

**"Котэ"** is a Runet meme meaning cuteness, kind of *kawai* in Japanese terms but less syrupy.

So it's a play on the contrast between fondness of guns or occupation in some enforcement agency and having a cute bubble gum sticker on a weapon.

[Here](http://wikireality.ru/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8D)'s a relevant article with some background on the meme (rus).

The poem itself is incidentally written in a meter similar (likely unintentionally) to the Japanese *haiku*.

Comment: I don't think *poroshki* poems are in any way related to haikus. They're a development on *pirozhki*, the deadpan blank-verse quatrains which are AFAIK a wholly Russian internet phenomenon. perhaps with a small nod to limericks. *Poroshki* shortened the last line to a single mora and introduced a rhyme in it.

Comment: @Nikolay Ershov thank you for mentioning them, although i'm familiar with the phenomenon i admit i didn't know or remember their name, that's why i glossed over them... the similarity of the genre with *haiku* could have well been unintentional, but here i think it works well with cuteness which can be alluded to Japanese pop-culture

Comment: still there's some affinity to Japanese poetry as according to the [Lurkmore's](http://lurkmore.to/%D0%9F%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%B8) article on *pirozhki* their original creator was a user of the now defunct *hokku.ru*